# String different values when using same script on different objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a bit confused here and need help. I've made a script which uses other script to calculate fuel and nitro consumption. Everything works as far as in inspector. But when it comes to stringing values in Text in game's UI, it only strings for 1 vehicle. I know that the issue is that since I use the same script on multiple objects, it just cannot work this way. I'm just confused what should I do about it.

Right now, I string this in Update:

```
fuelAmountText.text = string.Format ("{0}", FuelTankCapacity.ToString("F2"));
nitroAmounText.text = string.Format ("{0}", nitroAmount.ToString("F1"));
```

How do I make it only string for specific vehicle and not counter react with each other? Here's a full script in case if I'm confusing anyone:

```
public class CarFuel : MonoBehaviour {

    // car nitro and fuel indicators

    public Text fuelAmountText;

    public float nitroAmount;
    public Text nitroAmounText;

    // ref to car controller
    private RCC_CarControllerV3 carController;

    // dashboard canvas gameobject

    public GameObject customDash;

    public GameObject player;

    // engine type ------- wip

    //public EngineType engineTypeChoice = EngineType.v6;
    //public enum EngineType{i4, v6, v8, v12}

    // fuel tank capacity
    public float FuelTankCapacity;

    // cylinder amount of a vehicle
    public float cylAmt;

    void Awake(){

        carController = GetComponent<RCC_CarControllerV3>();

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        fuelAmountText.text = string.Format ("{0}", FuelTankCapacity.ToString("F2"));
        nitroAmounText.text = string.Format ("{0}", nitroAmount.ToString("F1"));


        nitroAmount = carController.NoS;

        // calculate fuel consumption

        if (carController.engineRunning == true) {

            FuelTankCapacity -= carController.rawEngineRPM * 0.00000001f + cylAmt * 0.0000015f;

        }

        // enable dash if car is being used

        if (carController.canControl == true) {

            customDash.SetActive (true);

        } else {

            customDash.SetActive (false);

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it more and debugging it, I found out the cause of the issue...

It was

```
if (carController.canControl == true)
```

What I did instead is I checked if Player GameObject was active or not, to display custom dash. And it worked. Phew. Can't believe I wasted so much time on this.